# Are there external drive enclosures yet with a Thunderbolt interface?

Tags: external-disk, thunderbolt

I'd like to put some spare disks in enclosures and use the Thunderbolt interface. Does such a thing exist yet? I can't find any. Are there technical issues or licensing restrictions that have stopped this? My searches have turned up no general purpose enclosures and I find that surprising.

This seems like a ServerFault issue but I was sent packing here instead.

Comment: I was looking for this a couple of days ago and found nothing other than an announced product with no market date.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from Apple.com

> Promise Pegasus R4 and Pegasus R6,
>   LaCie Little Big Disk and 2big,
>   Seagate GoFlex Thunderbolt Adapter,
>   Elgato Thunderbolt SSD.

Comment: Thanks but those already come with _drives_ (other than the proprietary Seagate adapter). I am looking for an **empty enclosure** into which I can put a drive that I already have. Something much simpler than a $1000 multi-drive RAID stack.

Comment: I believe that the GoFlex adapters use SATA internally, so you may be able to use one as a generic TB --> SATA adapter.  Google "goflex bare sata" for examples of others trying this.

Answer (score 0):

The new [Drobo 5D](http://www.drobo.com/products/professionals/drobo-5d/index.php) and [Drobo mini](http://www.drobo.com/products/professionals/drobo-mini/index.php) are both thunderbolt enabled, empty enclosures. Who knows when they'll ship though :/

Comment: At $849 and $649, I don't think those are simple HD enclosures.